# Problems to append tuples from a list to another and print it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print an list of tuples by comparing the tuple first item to a specified int() but by some mystery reason the tuples with 0 in second term just disappear

The code:

```
n_vertical = 3
n_horizontal = 3
for x in range(0,n_vertical):
    for y in range(0,n_horizontal):
        area.append((x,y,0))

print(area)
print('''
''')
def representacao_do_mapa(modo):
    if modo == 1:
        n=0
        l_c = []
        for x in area:
            if x[0] == n:
                l_c.append(x)
            else:
                print(l_c)
                l_c = []
                n+=1
representacao_do_mapa(1)
```

[image: screenshot of output]

Textual output:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0)]
[(1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0)]
```

Comment: The code does exactly what you said it to do: when it encounters `(n+1,0,0)`, it prints all accumulated elements, increases `n` and goes to the next item. You may be more worried that it doesn't print `(9,*,0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

You are throwing away the tuple `x` when you create the new list:

> ```
>         if x[0] == n:
>             l_c.append(x)       # here you append x
>         else:
>             print(l_c)          # here you print but do nothing with x
>             l_c = []            # list empty, x is missing
>             n+=1
> ```

**Solution**

```
def representacao_do_mapa(modo):
    if modo == 1:
        n=0
        l_c = []
        for x in area:
            if x[0] == n:
                l_c.append(x)
            else:
                print(l_c)
                l_c = [x]       # fix here
                n+=1
        print(l_c)              # fix here 

representacao_do_mapa(1)
```

---

Beside that - your last list is not going to be printed because the last `l_c` never get's into the printing part of your code - you have to add that ouside the for-loop over area.

Output (for `n_vertical = 3` and `n_horizontal = 3`:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0)]
[(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0)]
[(2, 0, 0), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0)]
```

---

**Optimizations:**

You can shorten your code using list comprehensions and list decomposition:

```
n_vertical = 3
n_horizontal = 3
area = [ (x,y,0) for x in range(n_horizontal) for y in range(n_vertical )]
# create with inner lists
area2 = [ [(x,y,0) for x in range(n_horizontal)] for y in range(n_vertical)]

print(area)

# print each inner list on new line
print(*area2, sep="\n")
```

---

Or you can print directly from `area`:

```
print(* (area[i*n_horizontal:i*n_horizontal+n_horizontal] 
         for i in range(n_vertical)) , sep="\n")
```

using a generator expression to slice `area` into `n_horizontal` pieces.

---

More on generator / list expressions: [Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

More on chunking lists: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

More on list slicing: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

More on printing: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: Wow, my bad! love u all. I would like to have reputation for like u answers. Thank u very much

Comment: @marcos and another edit to print your original tuple list directly using list slicing and print